# How do I remove this Cmake error while building a simulator for movesense

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code, cmake, movesense

I am trying to build the simulator for movesense using the link here[enter link description here](http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/).

```
root@51d079e11330:/movesense/simbuild# cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DMOVESENSE_CORE_LIBRARY=../MovesenseCoreLib/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../samples/blinky_app
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Visual Studio 15 2017

Generators
* Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

Comment: All tags on the dockerhub are for `linux/amd64`, see https://hub.docker.com/r/movesense/sensor-build-env/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated . This should explain why there are no VS generators available in the docker image. As far as I can tell briefly reading though the linked website the part involving Visual Studio lists instructions that start from scratch and are not meant to be run in a docker container but on a Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Either your version of CMake is way too old (so it doesn't support Visual Studio) or, more likely, you are not running it on Windows.

CMake will only generate a project format that is supported by the platform you are running CMake on.  For instance, on macOS, it gives exactly the options you are seeing, but on Windows you can also generate projects for Borland, Visual Studio, MinGW etc.

Comment: I am not running the windows Cmake on windows I am running it using docker....So what do you suggest I should do? I am reffering this doc http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/

Comment: It says "The simulator build creates a Windows executable that is based on the Movesense simulation framework. At this time the only supported environments for building and running the simulated sensor software are Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 on Microsoft Windows operating systems". Docker is basically a Linux machine, even when run on windows. I think the docs are a bit unclear, but that specific simulator cannot be built on docker.... You need windows.

Comment: Thank you c.fogelklou. I resolved the issue I ran the CMake on my windows laptop itself (not on docker)  using an older version of studio code and I was able to generate the CMAKE files